# How can I keep screenshots from impacting readability of text?

Tags: support, user-interface, images

I posted [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312094/72448) that included several screenshots from my iPhone. When I view the answer, however, the images make it hard to read the text of my answer. They seem too large, and they are aligned to the *left* of my text. The white background of the screenshot also blends in to the white background of the SE site.

I've had this problem in the past, and I've tried a couple things. One, is I sometimes add a frame around my image. I also try to reduce its size by 50%. Not only is this a lot of extra work, but I'm still not satisfied with the output.

Is there a better way to handle this issue? Is there some sort of markup that I can add when posting an image that will make things look better?

I presume I'm not the first one to encounter this problem, but I don't see an answer here on Ask Different Meta.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161111/automatically-resize-high-resolution-screenshots, particularly the use of  `<img ... >`